# Ubuntu 22.04 Internet Delay

Tags: internet, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I've just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04, and then to 22.04, via do-release-upgrade. My computer is now exhibiting unusual internet behavior. Each time I navigate to a webpage, start a download, run a speed test, etc. there's a delay of 5-10 seconds before it begins whatever work it's doing. This issue also occurs when trying to ping anything besides my DNS (8.8.8.8). Once it's connected, the connection remains stable, and operates at full expected speed. I am connected via ethernet and do not have wifi.

I have a suspicion this may be a DNS issue. I'm not sure if it's on my end or the actual DNS, but the timing is close enough that it made me raise an eyebrow. Additionally, other devices (windows computer on ethernet, wifi-connected phone) do not have this issue.

Comment: Update - it appears an installation of Pi-hole was the culprit. After uninstalling it (farewell, ad-free wifi!) my connection returned to normal speed.

Comment: Very interesting.  I have used a Raspberry Pi with pi-hole on it for a very long time now and I have updated to 22.04 LTS without any speed cut happening.  I do let all of my DNS go through it, but I do also have my router give out both the Pi and itself as DNS servers with the Pi being primary (in case I need to reboot the Pi during a time when people are using the internet as to not have an interruption).  I have also setup my Pi to use Cloudflare's DNS (cloudflared) and I have never looked back since.